# i got values from recyclerview using holder i want to transfer that data to another recycerview adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i got values from recyclerview using holder

i want to transfer that data to another recycerview adapter

like shopping cart to my cart page

heres my code

```
From a RecyclerView Adapter
button=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String productName= og.getProduct_name();
        String productPrice=og.getProduct_discountPrice();
        String id=og.getProduct_id();
        String category=og.getCategory_id();
        String imageUrl=og.getImageUrl();
        Toast.makeText(context1, "Product Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("pds","products are "+ productName + productPrice +" id is " + id +" c id is "+ category +" url "+ imageUrl);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context1,CartPageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("finProductName",productName);
        intent.putExtra("finProductPrice",productPrice);
        intent.putExtra("finId",id);
        intent.putExtra("finCategory",category);
        intent.putExtra("finImageUrl",imageUrl);
        context1.startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

I dont know how to pass values

i got values from recyclerview using holder

i want to transfer that data to another recycerview adapter

like shopping cart to my cart page

Answer (score 0):

**You can use state management tool REDUX**
[Redux repo](https://yarikx.github.io/Reductor-introduction/)

**or you can use public static variables it's simple way**

```
Class A{
   public static int shared_id=1;
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        shared_id=2;
     }
}
Class B{
 System.out.println(A.shared_id);
}
```